Crystal Reports: Get difference between the value from 2 different dates
I am using Crystal Reports.
I am trying to get the difference between the last date of the year and the first date of the year for each year.
Last date is a variable
First date is a variable
Formula to retrieve the first and last date is as follows:
Numbervar FirstDate; numbervar LastDate; if{@MyDate}={@Day First} then FirstDate:= {vehaudfl.aud_trans_lfmeter} Else if {@MyDate}={@Day Last} then LastDate:= {vehaudfl.aud_trans_lfmeter}
I tried to create the following formula to get the difference but keep getting the following error:
Error: "the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula."
For the formula:
Numbervar:=LastDate-FirstDate
FirstDate and LastDate are number variables and not date types. It's the first date's odometer and the last date's odometer.
lfmeter stands for "life meter."

Change
Numbervar:=LastDate-FirstDate

to simply
LastDate-FirstDate

Numbervar is not a variable name. It is part of the declaration of a numeric variable.  And there is no need to assign the expression value to a variable. The formula would simply return the value of the last expression inside the formula definition.

(my Crystal Reports skills are so rusty as to be basically non-existent, but) I think maybe you meant: change A to simply LastDate-FirstDate

Yes, just edited to fix the typo.
